# Cordova Angular Background-Image does not work for one image (same path for different image works)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, background-image, angular5

I have the following problem with my angular 5 app that I want deployed on android with cordova :S in my scss file i have

```
  background: url("./../../assets/nav/ChatBackground.png");
```

in my component. 
the same line in my app.component.scss works (with one less ../) :S I just don't get it...
which works if I i use "ng serve --open" and it also works on my phone (deployed via cordova) if I use a different Image in the same directory like

```
  background: url("./../../assets/nav/NavImage.png");
```

Everything seems to work fine 
in my www folder (in the cordova project) both files are present but if I link to the first one (ChatBackground.png) it does not work while for NavImage.png it works (yes the path is correct because my IDE autocompletes it for me) :S
please I have no idea what I am doing wrong :S

```
  //background-image instead of background does not work either
  //different path does not compile 
  //<img src="samePath"> does not work for any image so maybe the issue is there but I don't know where...

Not Working: 
Request URL:http://localhost:4200/ChatScreenBackground.cca3b844d2e54ccfdfcc.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Working: 
Request URL:data:image/png;base64,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(LOTS OF CHARACTERS THAT I CUT OUT TO NOT DISPLAY THEM HERE)5bBHwC9rVVR+0eg0uAZLDL8CwiVrOVQ9bL+1xukuA5CFCvLZ85bmB7DI6lwDJRYJ6Wpg0Cqnq3hZH2SVAcvoFWtKoTRV+yL0z6UUCnxoluHBhL/4vwABHmEZReUh1TQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from memory cache)
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```